# Specified cast not valid Sqlquery

Tags: c#, sql, casting

i am getting the error Specified cast not valid when reading from an SQL Select statement in C#.

my data types for those are uniqueidentifier, tinyint, tinyint.

any suggestions on why this is happening?

```
connexTable.Rows.Add(
                (Guid)reader["VehicleId"], 
                (bool)reader["Sensor1"], 
                (bool)reader["Sensor2"]
                );
```

Thanks,

Comment: Why the double post? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28573159/specified-cast-not-valid-sqlquery

Comment: My mistake, thought that it didnt post, im on my mobile, could t find it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SQl -> c#
tinyint -> byte
bit -> bool
```

Answer (score 2):

tinyint = byte, could you add C# definition of connexTable

Comment: The table is boolean, i need to change my sql table then